# Pyspark RDD column value selection

Tags: pyspark, lambda, rdd

I have a rdd like this:

```
|item_id|   recommendations|
+-------+------------------+
|      1|[{810, 5.2324243},{134, 4.58323},{810, 4.89248}]
|     23|[[{1643, 5.1180077}, {1463, 4.8429747}, {1368, 4.4758873}]
```

if I want to only extract the first value in each {} from col "recommendations".

Expected result looks like this:

```
|item_id|   recommendations|
+-------+------------------+
|      1|[{810, 134, 810}]
|     23|[{1643, 1463, 1368}]
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your data is an rdd or a dataframe, so I provide both here. Overall, from your sample data, I assume your `recommendations` is **an array of struct type**. You will know the exact columns by running `df.printSchema()` (if it was a dataframe) or `rdd.first()` (if it was an rdd). I created a dummy schema with two columns `a` and `b`.

###### This is my "dummy" class

```py
class X():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

###### This is my "dummy" data

```py
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('id', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('rec', T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
        T.StructField('a', T.IntegerType()),
        T.StructField('b', T.FloatType()), 
    ])))
])

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, [X(810, 5.2324243), X(134, 4.58323), X(810, 4.89248)]),
    (23, [X(1643, 5.1180077), X(1463, 4.8429747), X(1368, 4.4758873)])
], schema)
```

###### If your data is a dataframe

```py
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()

+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|id |rec                                                      |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{810, 5.2324243}, {134, 4.58323}, {810, 4.89248}]       |
|23 |[{1643, 5.1180077}, {1463, 4.8429747}, {1368, 4.4758873}]|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rec: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: float (nullable = true)

(df
    .select('id', F.explode('rec').alias('rec'))
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(F.collect_list('rec.a').alias('rec'))
    .show()
)

+---+------------------+
| id|               rec|
+---+------------------+
|  1|   [810, 134, 810]|
| 23|[1643, 1463, 1368]|
+---+------------------+
```

###### If your data is an rdd

```
dfrdd = df.rdd
dfrdd.first()

# Row(id=1, rec=[Row(a=810, b=5.232424259185791), Row(a=134, b=4.583230018615723), Row(a=810, b=4.89247989654541)])

(dfrdd
    .map(lambda x: (x.id, [r.a for r in x.rec]))
    .toDF()
    .show()
)
+---+------------------+
| _1|                _2|
+---+------------------+
|  1|   [810, 134, 810]|
| 23|[1643, 1463, 1368]|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank a lot! But in my case I can not specific the first element as "a". Is there any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what’s your schema then?

Comment: oops I forgot to map it to my schema, solved it! Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer to close the thread :)